# Placing text in an contend box

Tags: java, swing, graphics, paint

Ive got a problem with placing String text in my frame, using paintComponent method.

It Looks like that:

[image]

I dunno why it doesn't want to place String in proper place, given that I've even counted pixels.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class FrameMain {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            JFrame frame = new DrawFrame();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });

}


public class DrawFrame extends JFrame {

public DrawFrame()
{
    setTitle("Frame with a component containing String");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds (100, 100, 300, 300 );
    DrawComponent draw = new DrawComponent();
    add(draw);

}


public class DrawComponent extends JComponent {

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.drawString("First string in component located in frame", WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    final int WIDTH = 175;
    final int HEIGHT = 200;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
g.drawString("First string in component located in frame", WIDTH, HEIGHT);
//final int WIDTH = 175;
//final int HEIGHT = 200;
```

Never define a variable after you use it. WIDTH and HEIGHT are variables from other Swing class that default to 0.

```
final int WIDTH = 175;
final int HEIGHT = 200;
g.drawString("First string in component located in frame", WIDTH, HEIGHT);
```

Edit:

> I want the String to set position given the size of frame, not position of it.

Don't do custom painting. Use a JLabel.

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("centered");
label.setHorizontalAlignment( JLabel.CENTER );
frame.add(label);
```

Answer (score 2):

The Problem is you have

```
 final int WIDTH = 175;
 final int HEIGHT = 200;
```

declared *after* `drawString(..., WIDTH, HEIGHT)`

What is happening is that `JComponent` also has a contant `HEIGHT` and `WIDTH`, so the `drawString` is using the `WIDTH` and `HEIGHT` of `JComponet` and not the ones you declared.

If you want to use yours, then just place it *before* the `drawString`

```
final int WIDTH = 175;
final int HEIGHT = 200;
g.drawString("First string in component located in frame", WIDTH, HEIGHT);
```

---

**UPDATE**

To center the text, you need to use `FontMetrics`. See here

```
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        String message = "First string in component located in frame";
        Font font = new Font("impact", Font.PLAIN, 14);
        g.setFont(font);
        FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics(font);
        int stringWidth = fm.stringWidth(message);
        int height = fm.getAscent();
        int x = getWidth()/2 - stringWidth/2;
        int y = getHeight()/2 + height/2;
        g.drawString(message, x, y);    
    }
```

Comment: Thx a lot. Didn't see that, dumb me.
And what if I want to place the text in context of frame itself ?
F.e. I`d like to to draw the String in the middle of frame, without using specific pixel coorinates, I want the String to set position given the size of frame, not position of it.

Comment: @user3310825 see my **UPDATE**. You need to use `FontMetrics`. You can learn more [**here**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/measuringtext.html)